# Can someone provide information about "setScrollIndicators (View up, View down)"?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to get information about the functionality for the `AbsListView` method called:

[setScrollIndicators (View up, View down)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setScrollIndicators%28android.view.View,%20android.view.View%29)

But, as you can see in the link above, there is no documentation about that.

Also, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645005/android-what-listview-setscrollindicatorsup-down-does), but actually is even more confusing for me.

Can someone provide information about that method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That method should setts the arrows for a listView, if you want them.  I don't think it's really used any more though.